# Reassigning a displayed form or its controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form called `Dynamic` that houses 3 objects: 1 Listview and 2 Panels.

Since I want to integrate the ability to split forms (so that every object gets their own form), I'm using an external non-static class `Processor`. This is where everything on a window is processed and returned to the window. I'm updating all components in one, so when I initialize the window for instance, a method in the processor will create one listview and two panels:

```cs
public class Processor
{
    Dynamic d = null;

    public Processor()
    {

    }

    public Dynamic BuildWindow(Dynamic dyn)
    {
        d = dyn;

        d.Text = "Title"; // This does change the title of the form

        d.ControlList = BuildListView(); // These simply create a new control
        d.PanelPage = BuildPanelPage();  // with some settings.
        d.PanelSelection = BuildPanelSelection();

        return d;
    }
}
```

From the main window, the method is called like this:

```cs
public partial class Dynamic : Form
{
    Processor p = new Processor();

    public Dynamic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this = p.BuildWindow(this);
    }
}
```

I now get an error telling me that `<this>` is read-only. I tried converting the processor to a static class, but with no result. I also tried assigning the controls one by one:

```cs
this.ControlList = p.BuildListView();
this.PanelSelection = p.BuildPanelSelection();
this.PanelPage = p.BuildPanelPage();
```

This gives no errors, but it doesn't update the objects on the form either.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When creating UI objects on the fly in Windows Forms, you need to add them to the Controls collection of the Form:

```
this.ControlList = p.BuildListView();
this.PanelSelection = p.BuildPanelSelection();
this.PanelPage = p.BuildPanelPage();

this.Controls.Add(this.ControlList);
this.Controls.Add(this.PanelSelection);
this.Controls.Add(this.PanelPage);
```

Sidenote: [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a keyword, I would suggest you don't have classes that only differ from  C# keywords by capitalization.

Comment: The problem with this is that I use the same method to resize the controls. I that case, no new controls are being made, just some property changes.

Comment: @Anthony: you should first remove those controls from the designer completely, otherwise they are instantiated twice (once inside `InitializeComponent();`, and then replaced by new instances). Second, I doubt you need to handle resizing manually. Doesn't `Anchor` suit you? Or various layout containers?

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I'll look into that. Another problem I have is that the panels will hold various controls, and the processor will change some of those properties. I hope to be able to update the controls on a panel without constantly refreshing the whole panel.

Comment: @Anthony: what's the reason for creating new instances of these controls in the first place? Why don't you simply update their properties? Your approach unnecesarily wastes CPU cycles and GC time by creating new instances and disposing them.

Comment: Well, I thought this would be easier to just call one method (`BuildWindow(this);`), change controls and return the entire form to update all at once. That, or Change Controls and re-add them to the form, this because of the functionality I want to include (the ability to split the windows). When a window is splitted, I want to be able to use the same methods as if there was just one window. Therefor I thought to use one method, that returns the object. I'm now thinking of integrating the forms in the processor, maybe this way I'll be able to adapt everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. You cannot change `this`. Doing it inside a constructor is especially strange. If you have a new instance of a form, you can assign it to the variable which previously pointed to the old instance, but that doesn't mean that the old instance would somehow disappear. So, basically you would need to close the previous `Form` and the instantiate and show a new one (which seems unnecessary if you only need to *update* its contents).

As mentioned in one of the answers, you can add new instances to the `Controls` collection to make your `Form` render them, but the problem with this approach is that, if you're creating new controls in run-time, you cannot use the Visual Studio designer to define their appearance (which may or may not be a bad thing). You can certainly remove them from the designer and then create all of them at run time, but I still don't see why you would create new instances to do this.

I would recommend to create these controls inside Visual Studio designer, and then simply update their properties in runtime, without creating new instances at all. I.e.:

```
public partial class DynamicForm : Form
{
    Processor p = new Processor();

    public DynamicForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // this doesn't create a new instance
        p.UpdateWindow(this);
    }
}
```

Similarly, all your updating methods should merely *update* controls, not create new ones:

```
class Processor 
{
    public void UpdateWindow(DynamicForm form)
    {
        form.Text = "Title";
        UpdateListView(form.ControlList); 
        ...
    }

    public void UpdateListView(ListView listView)
    {
        listView.Clear();
        listView.AddItem(...)
    }
}
```

An even better approach would be to expose this functionality through an interface of your `DynamicForm`, to avoid making these controls `public`. This would mean that your `Form` might have a method like this:

```
public partial class DynamicForm : Form, IDynamicView
{
    public void AddItemToControlList(SomeItem item)
    {
        this.ControlList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Which is defined through an interface like this:

```
public interface IDynamicView
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public void AddItemToControlList(SomeItem item);
     // other methods you want to expose (...)
}
```

and then your `Processor` would only be "allowed" to access the methods specified in your interface:

```
class Processor 
{
    // note the use of interface instead of actual form
    public void UpdateWindow(IDynamicView view)
    {
        view.Text = "hello";
        view.AddItemToControlList( some item );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem comes with understanding of programming keywords, "this" is not a parameter which you can assign and hence you cannot set a value to it.

Also looking at the code I do not think that BuildWindow(this) needs to return anything since you have already passed a reference "this" to the Processor class and you are setting values in the processor class to "this" already. So even if you make BuildWindow(Dynamic dyn) as void return type and remove setting to this you will have your panels and listView updated if rest of the code is written correctly.

You will still need to do what nvoigt said above, that  to display all your controls you need to add them to your form else they will not be displayed